# Why I got an 'en' include file while using awk to search for 'em' regex keyword?

Tags: regex, awk

I was learning awk regex search.

Under \etc path I did this command:

```
ls -l | awk '/em/ { print $9}'
```

And the output is this:

```
aptdaemon
at.deny
emacs
gnome-settings-daemon
systemd
```

I'm wondering why this 'at.deny' file was shown in the result?
Shouldn't /em/ just search for file name which contains 'em'?

Comment: what does this give you: `ls -l at.deny` ? I bet there's "em" in that line...

Comment: Can you paste the whole `ls -l` output? `/em/` is looking for all the line and just printing the 9th field, so most probably there is some `em` around in that lien.

Comment: @ChrisMaes yes. there is a item called 'daemon' in the fourth column, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

`ls -l` will print more than just the name of files in the current directory, if you do `ls -l at.deny` I'm sure you will find a `em` somewhere in there.

Your current command to `awk` is searching the **entire** line, not just what happens to be in column `$9`, and then print the contents of column `$9`.

---

**THE SOLUTION**

If you just want to search, and print, the specified column, do so with the following:

```
ls -l | awk '($9 ~ /em/) { print $9 }'
```

---

**CONCERNS**

As expressed by @[EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton):

> you can't guarantee that $9 is the location of the [full] file name in ls output. $NF would be closer but still wouldn't account for file names that contain spaces. The better response is that you shouldn't try to parse the output of ls (google it).

The snippet in questions suffer from other flaws than the most obvious one, if you are trying to find the files in the current directory that matches a certain pattern, you should use something like [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -name '*em*'
```

<sup>The above would output all files in the current directory (`.`) (`-maxdepth 0` is to prevent `find` from diving into subdirectories), having `em` in their name. If you'd like to use *regular expressions*  please see the `-regex` switch in `man find`.</sup>.

Comment: To the one giving this post **-1**, care to elaborate? The post answers what OP is asking, as well as providing OP with means to do it in the "expected" manner.

Comment: Yo can remove the parentheses. `awk '$9~/em/ {print $9}'`

Comment: @Jotne Correct! this is purely a stylistic alternative, personally I find it clearer to keep the parentheses; grouping the `cond` and `result` into two individual segments.

Comment: I didn't give it a `-1` but I'd bet you got it because you can't guarantee that `$9` is the location of the [full] file name in `ls` output. `$NF` would be closer but still wouldn't account for file names that contain spaces. The better response is that you shouldn't try to parse the output of `ls` (google it).

Comment: @EdMorton honestly it doesn't really matter in this case. OP is asking why non-matching data is printed (through `$9`) even though s/he does matching through `/em/`. The post contains the answer.

Comment: That's why I personally didn't downvote it since you DID answer the specific question, but I could understand others downvoting it since it doesn't advise the OP that that's the wrong approach. It's a bit like if someone points a gun at their foot and asks how to load the gun. You can tell them how to do it and you'd have provided the correct answer, but it might be even more useful to them in the long run to suggest they point the gun elsewhere.

Comment: @EdMorton post edited to reflect the concerns raised, thanks.

Comment: In the end you basically copied my answer

Comment: @perreal the intent for both posts are the same, I did not "copy" your answer (honestly I didn't even look at it until you now commented on mine). Though now I learned that `find` implicitly uses `.` if the directory isn't explicitly stated, when reading your post.

Answer (score 5):

It is matching some other column, try a search on the desired one only:

```
ls -l | awk '$9 ~ /em/ { print $9}'
```

It might be better to use find though:

```
find -maxdepth 0 -name '*em*'
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just:

```
ls *em* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: **-1**: this might not be enough, as an example `zsh` will still complain. It also doesn't answer what OP is asking, namely; **why?**.

Comment: +1 this is the right way to simply list files whose name contains `em`